# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in web-server project of Nodejs-complete-course

Tags: node.js, callback

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./src/app.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./src/app.js`
Server is up on port 3000
/Users/xyz/Node-Course/web-app/src/utils/geocode.js:18
        latitude: body.features[0].center[1],
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I am unable to debug this error occurs when i try to fetch a geo-codes[latitude, longitude] for a location using mapbox.com using callback and destructuring.

Comment: You should add the code where you're doing the request and processing the response.

Comment: As described in the log, body.features has null value or undefined. Try to check your mapbox api is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

There was modification in API access token in the code while fetching the json data from API.If you are facing similar error than try verifying the access token in your code.